# Check paginated currentPage before setting the paginate tag

Tags: pagination

This might sound counter-intuitive, but I'm trying to set a specific limit; if the `currentPage` is the first paginated entry.

```
{% set limit = paginate.currentPage == 1 ? 5 : 8 %}
{% paginate craft.entries.section('news').limit(limit) as articles %}
```

I know this isn't going to work because I'm querying the `paginate` tag before I've set it.

So is there a way to set a custom limit for the first page only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so after discovering the [getPageNum](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.request#getPageNum) request, I found the following solution:

```
{% set pageNumber = craft.request.getPageNum %}
{% set firstPageLimit = 5 %}
{% set defaultLimit = 8 %}
{% set limit = pageNumber == 1 ? firstPageLimit : defaultLimit %}
{% set offset = pageNumber == 1 ? 0 : firstPageLimit - defaultLimit %}
{% paginate craft.entries.section('news').limit(limit).offset(offset) as articles %}
```

Comment: Whoa, so easy! Thank you for posting this solution.

Comment: Can you please post it here as well: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/6843/sensible-way-to-have-different-number-of-entries-on-page-one-of-pagination